# presenting a view not working in iphone

Tags: iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to navigate from one page to another on a button click in a facebook appliaction.
I am using

```
registerUser=[[RegisterPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"RegisterPage" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController :registerUser animated:YES];
```

for presenting the next view after getting response from facebook.
But it is not showing the next view. It works fine in all other places where I used to present other views.

Anyone have idea about this issue?

Comment: "bundle:nil" could be a problem, please user [NSBundle mainBundle].

Comment: No you don't have to put `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. From the docs: "If nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle.".

Comment: if self is a viewcontroller then it's definitely work.otherwise you can try this also [self.navigationController presentModalViewController :registerUser animated:YES];

Comment: i used self.navigationController presentModalViewController :registerUser animated:YES];.but it also didnt work.if i try to dismiss a view at this place,it works.but not presenting another view.

Comment: it mean's there are some other issues in your code.these lines working correctly.check your code briefly.

Comment: @mudit bajpal,is it an issue of setting the view in the app delegate?i think that may be the issue

Comment: yes,i think it may be an issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everyones reply.i have solved it after a long fight.i just dismissed the view before pesenting the next view and set dismissmodalviewcontrollerAnimated to NO.`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                    nextview = [[LoginPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];
                    [self  presentModalViewController: nextview animated:YES];`hope this help someone like me

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is 'self' here? Is it a viewcontroller? Or just a UIView?
I think this'll only work if self is a viewcontroller or some subclass of it.

Comment: hmm, then please share some more code, it's not clear now why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

My code to present a view controller is somewhat like yours (without a nib):

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

And to present a navigation controller it's like this (without a nib):

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]       initWithRootViewController:controller];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
[controller release];
```

Sometimes simply copying someones code helps.